# How to debug Node 8 app?

Tags: node.js

My [node inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/) failed after I upgraded to Node 8. It was working on Node 6. I am using MacOS. What is the best way to debug node 8 app?  I tried to re-install node inspector again, then got the following error msg:

```
➜  ~ sudo npm install -g node-inspector

> v8-profiler@5.7.0 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-profiler
> node -e 'process.exit(0)'


> v8-debug@1.0.1 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug
> node -e 'process.exit(0)'

/usr/local/bin/node-inspector -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/bin/inspector.js
/usr/local/bin/node-debug -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/bin/node-debug.js

> v8-debug@1.0.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/debug/v1.0.1/node-v57-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for v8-debug@1.0.1 and node@8.3.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/debug/v1.0.1/node-v57-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for v8-debug@1.0.1 and node@8.3.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v1.0.1/node-v57-darwin-x64/debug.node" "--module_name=debug" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v1.0.1/node-v57-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug
gyp ERR! node -v v8.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v1.0.1/node-v57-darwin-x64/debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v1.0.1/node-v57-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.3.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v1.0.1/node-v57-darwin-x64/debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v1.0.1/node-v57-darwin-x64' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! v8-debug@1.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shenxinxu/.npm/_logs/2017-08-16T14_32_27_981Z-debug.log
```

Comment: there is a chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nim-node-inspector-manage/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj) if you haven't tried yet

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js

Comment: For future reference: rather than using `npm install -g`, a nice alternative is to only install `npx` globally, which you can then use to run any *locally* installed dependency. So you install npx, then with `node-inspector` installed *locally* you can invoke it either by npm script the way you already do (since npm scripts have been able to run cli utils from node_module since forever) or through `npx clicommand`, so you can run grunt, jshint, babel, etc. etc. without ever needing to install them globally, and running into versioning insanity.